# Promise is undefined in sub iframe in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, promise

Does anybody solving the isse that native Promise object is present in IE11, but is not present in sub iframe?

Comment: Please provide small example code that illustrates the problem. I just tried in IE11 and the `Promise` object is available in a page that is loaded via `<iframe src="...."></iframe>`

Comment: `native Promise object is present in IE11` - no it isn't

Comment: You are right. The Promise object is not present automatically. I have some babel generated code wich inject Promise to main frame.